# RMON2 on cisco switches

Tags: monitoring, cisco, snmp

I am investigating using RMON for traffic analysis.
Can I use a Catalyst 3560 to monitor traffic over it using RMON2?
I have RMON options from the IOS but some of the options I thought I should have appear to be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO. RMON 1 is all that is available on this switch. It kinda looks like RMON is ignored nowadays.